# How to change each column's width individually?

Tags: html, html-table

In JavaScript, one style width value is set for all columns, and I can't resize them one by one. I need to resize columns one by one, not all at once:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="detailed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>C1</th>
        <th>C2</th>
        <th>C3</th> 
        <th>C4</th>
        <th>C5</th>
        <th>C6</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    {% for col in cols %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{  col.name1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{  col.name2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{  col.name3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{  col.name4 }}</td>
                    <td>{{  col.name5 }}</td>
                    <td>{{  col.name6 }}</td>             
                </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nth-child to change individual column's width. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/na1derLk/)

```
tr>td:nth-child(1){
  width:100px;
}

tr>td:nth-child(4){
  width:450px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , can you please provide me more details on how to find the right css file in order to implement these changes

Comment: @ciprigothic either put this between `<style></style>` tags in the `head` of your html or create a new file name whateveryouwant.css and link to it with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../whateveryouwant.css">` changing the `href` to the path to the file.  If you're using bootstrap make sure this link is after the bootstrap link so it overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assign an id (or class if you want to change some cells but not all.) to the  tags. Then of course use normal CSS to change width, height or padding, etc.

PS. On my phone right now, hard to provide any sample code. Feel free to suggest edit.

Comment: Thank you , can you please provide me more details on how to find the right css file in order to implement these changes

Answer (score 0):

Add to table

```
width: 100%
```

Next you can add something like this to each TH :

```
<th style="width: 10%; padding: 5px;">C1</th>
```

Or (best option i think) add to th class and set there a css

```
<th class="nameClass">C2</th>
```

Style CSS:

```
.nameClass {
  width: 10%; // could be other value in px, inc etc.
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Better options to make this is from user below :P

Comment: Thank you , can you please provide me more details on how to find the right css file in order to implement these changes

Comment: Your main CSS file. If you only use boostrap.min.css etc then just create new one css file, Add that to header (below boostrap.css) and add this with table css. Should be enought